# facing issue of unique key, while using map_ array

Tags: arrays, react-native, dictionary, unique-key

```
    {multiList.map((item,index)=>
     <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
     <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {}}
       style={styles.GridViewBlockStyle}
     >
       <Text style={styles.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}>
         {item.key}
       </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
    )}
```

error
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" pro

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 {multiList.map((item,index)=>
     <View key={index} style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}> // pass unique key here
     <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {}}
       style={styles.GridViewBlockStyle}
     >
       <Text style={styles.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}>
         {item.key}
       </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to supply a key (a prop called 'key') to the component you are rendering.

```
<View 
   key={index}
```